# Cancel all pending axios request on error

Tags: javascript, axios, vuejs3, vite

I'm currently working in a Vue3 application using Axios. Basically my use case is that I have a global loading indicator that is activated using a request interceptor and then deactivated in the response interceptor. This work brilliantly with pages that only have a single api request. This becomes and issue when we have concurrent requests.

I've been looking here on S.O. and I can't seem to find a good solution. I know that you can cancel requests using the AbortController, but the axios docs arent too detailed on this.
https://github.com/axios/axios#abortcontroller
What I want to happen is if my previous request returns an exception, I want the cancel the remaining pending calls.

I'm also wondering if this could accomplished with some sort of queue system? I cant seem to find any best practices that address this issue.

TIA!

axiosClient.ts

```
// we first import the axios library
import { notify } from '@/services/notificationService';
import axios, { AxiosError } from 'axios';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
import { EnvironmentEnum } from './interfaces/environment-enum';
import { useConfigStore } from '@/stores/configuration-store';
import axiosRetry from 'axios-retry';

const axiosClient = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
});

axiosRetry(axios, {
    retries: 3,
    retryDelay: () => {
        return 1000;
    },
});

/** Adding the response interceptors */
axiosClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    const store = useConfigStore();
    const { isLoading } = storeToRefs(useConfigStore());
    const { selectedEnvironment } = storeToRefs(store);
    config.baseURL = `${EnvironmentEnum[selectedEnvironment.value]}/`;
    isLoading.value = true;
    return config;
});

axiosClient.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        const { isLoading } = storeToRefs(useConfigStore());
        isLoading.value = false;
        return Promise.resolve(response);
    },
    (error: AxiosError) => {
        const { isLoading } = storeToRefs(useConfigStore());
        isLoading.value = false;
        notify(error.code === 'ERR_NETWORK' ? error.message : `${JSON.stringify(error.response?.data)}`, 'danger');
    }
);

export default axiosClient;
```

component

```
const search = () => {
    const data = ref();
    let result = await call1();
    if(result && result.status == 200)
    data.value = await call2();
};
```

Comment: Please put the related code on your question.
How are you calling all those request? are those request sequential? are those request paralell? do you execute them all at once?

Comment: @Pipe I can provide the related code, but I dont think it will actually provide anything beneficial. I'm calling 3 requests. First there is a call get to get some User identity info. I think make a trip back for one set of data, and then a separate set of data. These two sets are then combined in a edit form.

The issue is that in the axiosClient I set is loading to true in the request interceptor and then false when the response is intercepted. If a error is caught, I also set is loading to false.

Comment: @Pipe -continued

If the identity call fails (most likely because of the network) I want to abandon the other two requests since the page will not work correctly without the identity info. 

The Identity call is made from a Pinia store and the other two for getting the data sets are awaited from the actual Vue component in the onMounted().

Comment: I think it will be beneficial. Your text description is not enough to help you with a solution. Also remember to check [ask] and [example]. All questions should include relevant code.

Comment: @Pipe I added my axiosClient info

Comment: Can you add the relevant code related with how do you make those calls?

Comment: @Pipe I added the basic function that its doing the causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From  [Axios.CancelToken](https://github.com/axios/axios#abortcontroller)

Pass cancelToken with API call, if any call gets cancelled all pending requests will stop by calling `source.cancel`

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  setup() {
    const cancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
    const source = cancelToken.source();
    const errorRef = ref(null);

    const makeRequests = async () => {
      try {
        await axios.get('/api/endpoint1', { cancelToken: source.token });
        await axios.get('/api/endpoint2', { cancelToken: source.token });
      } catch (error) {
       
          console.error('Error occurred:', error);
          errorRef.value = error;
          source.cancel('Request canceled due to an error');
        }
    };

    makeRequests();

    return {
      error: errorRef,
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: My understanding is that CancelToken has been deprecated and replaced by the AbortController